# Assigning point to customer C programming

Tags: c, file, text, authentication, system

I would like to get assistance in my coding. I created a customer loyalty system using C (using file) and now I need to assign some called points to my customer, but what happenned is it will not assign any points to them.

```
{
for (int i = 0; i < (count / 3); i++)
    {
        fscanf(reward_file, "%s\n%s\n%d\n", user[i].Username, user[i].Password, &user[i].Points);
        if (Point = user[i].Points)
        {
            strcpy(user[i].Points, Reward);
            Point = Point + Reward;
            printf("%d", Point);
            system("pause");;
        }
    }
    fclose(reward_file);
    FILE *new_file = fopen("CustomerRegistration.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfCust; i++)
    {
        fprintf(new_file, "%s\n%s\n%d\n", user[i].Username, user[i].Password, user[i].Points);
    }
    fclose(new_file);
    printf("You Have Successfully Added Your Point!!!\n");
    printf("You Will be Redirected Back to Customer Privilege Menu");
    system("TIMEOUT \t 5");
}
```

I am using struct for my customer and here is the code

```
struct USER
{
    char Username[255];
    char Password[255];
    int Points;
};
struct USER user[100];
```

Data is obtained from a function called "Login"

```
FILE *LOGINFILE = fopen("CustomerRegistration.txt", "r");
if (LOGINFILE) 
{
    system("cls");
    printf("!!!Hello Customer!!!\n");
    printf("Please type in your Username and Password\n");
    printf("Username\t: ");
    //while ((c = getchar()) !='\n');
    gets(UN);
    printf("Password\t: ");
    gets(Pswd);
```

I also assigned global variable called "Point"

```
int Point = 0;
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, edit your post and show us an example of your file content from which you are getting the input. What is the purpose of the Point variable ?

Comment: Hi @CioacaRadu I have edited my post, everything is separated into different function. The variable Point purpose is to assign the mathematic calculation. Am I wrong?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: `gets()` is obsolete, please use `fgets()` although they do not work in quite the same way.

Comment: Moreover, your code lacks the essential checks of the return values from library functions, such as `fopen` and `fscanf` etc. The use of `fscanf` should be more like `if(fscanf(reward_file, "%s%s%d", user[i].Username, user[i].Password, &user[i].Points) != 3) { /* flag an error */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am understanding from your posted code you want to add a Reward to the Customer Points.

Firstly you just need to add to user.Points the Reward, using strcpy makes no sense because that function is used for copying strings.

that if( Point = user[i].Points ) also makes no sense firstly because C equality condition is represented by a double equal sign ( "==" ) and you don't need to make that check.

The .Points member is an int and Reward is also an int ,so you can do arithmethic operations and there is no need to use another Point auxiliar.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (count / 3); i++)
        {
            fscanf(reward_file, "%s\n%s\n%d\n", user[i].Username, user[i].Password, &user[i].Points);

                user[i].Points += Reward;
                printf("%d", user[i].Points);

                system("pause");;

        }
 .....
```

Comment: it really works!!! Thank you so much dude!!! I really appreciate it. If I have another problem may I find you to help me?:D @CioacaRadu

Comment: I think that if you post good questions and wait long enough , stackoverflow will always help you.

Answer (score 0):

the first loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (count / 3); i++)
```

the second loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfCust; i++)
```

if NumOfCust is greater than (count/3)) you'll get unitialized values on CustomerRegistration.txt. I can't see the values of those variables, but make sure it doesn't happen. The best would be to use the last value of i in the first loop to the stop condition for the second loop.